# Simplifying an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators, simplification

I have a working solution for a problem found [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p199368).  After writing it, I noticed I have the exact same statement in both parts of the if/else:

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if(start >= nums.length) return target == 0;

  int next = start + 1;
  int cur = nums[start];

  if(cur == 6) return groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur);
  return groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur) || groupSum6(next, nums, target);
}
```

After a little retooling, I was able to 'simplify' the problem to this:

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if(start >= nums.length) return target == 0;

  int next = start + 1;
  int cur = nums[start];

  if(cur != 6) {
      boolean success = groupSum6(next, nums, target);
      if(success) return true;
  }
  return groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur);
}
```

I definitely prefer the second solution, even though it is a bit more verbose.  My question is, is there a way to simplify this even further?  Something seems off to me about having an if statement that returns true, but I might just be over analyzing the problem.  I ask solely for improving my logic simplification abilities, not because I think it is something that would be necessary to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here is more simplified.

```
public boolean groupSum6(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if(start >= nums.length) return target == 0;

  int next = start + 1;
  int cur = nums[start];

  boolean minusCur = groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur);
  return (cur == 6) ? minusCur : (minusCur || groupSum6(next, nums, target));
}
```

The lines I added will check if cur == 6 it will return minusCur and if not it will return `(minusCur || groupSum6(next, nums, target)));`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
return(cur == 6 ? groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur) : (groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur) || groupSum6(next, nums, target)))
```

Comment: The second part to that is suppose to return `(groupSum6(next, nums, target - cur) || groupSum6(next, nums, target))` not just `groupSum6(next, nums, target)`.